# Cmd + B key combination with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I'm trying to detect key combinations with jQuery, I've been researching for the last like, few hours trying to find a workable solution.  Seems like everything works great with the ctrl key but not the command key on a mac.  This code is almost just what I want, but how can I make it work with command?

```
$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args) {
    var isCtrl = false;
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(!args) args=[]; // IE barks when args is null

        if(e.ctrlKey) isCtrl = true;
        if(e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) && isCtrl) {
            callback.apply(this, args);
            return false;
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey) isCtrl = false;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (!args) { args = []; }
    if (e.which === 98 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) { // Ctrl + b
        callback.apply(this, args);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Why the keyup event? I could be wrong, but I think modifier keys don't work on `keyup()` but they do on `keydown()`.

Comment: Oh, well, what's `args`? What is it supposed to be? I just modified the relevant part of your code...

Comment: Also why `$.ctrl = function(key, callback, args)`??

Comment: Oh!  I see.  Got it working now.  It's a jquery plugin I found somewhere.